# How to use POST request in Django using graph api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, instagram-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Basically, I am trying to create a form that will create a new user in my Azure Active Directory.
According to the [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), I need to use the given HTTP request. 
can anybody please guide me on how to make it happen.
If code is provided then it will awesome, else explanation or guidance is also great.

I have been able to successfully run the tutorial code with GET requests. Now I wish to make POST requests with a graph_client.post(https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users, data={'userPrincipalName': 'sue@example.com', etc... }) type of construction. Unfortunately, this generates a HTTP 400 message of the form 'code': 'BadRequest', 'message': 'Entity only allows writes with a JSON Content-Type header.'. Will the tutorial constructs work with POST requests?

If you can guide me on where to add the lines to make a POST method work successfully. I am attaching screenshots of my code please find below:-

HTML page:-
[image]

views.py:-
[image]

graph_helper.py;-
[image]

Your time and effort will be appreciated.
Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that you're missing a `Content-Type` header in your POST. You're using the [Requests library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/), and their docs show how to make a POST.

Looking at your code, the first problem I see is that you're not sending anything:

```
new_user = graph_client.post('{0}/users'.format(graph_url))
```

As I recall, you need to explicitly set the `Content-Type` header, otherwise the Requests library sends anything you pass in the `data` parameter as form-encoded, which won't work. So you'd have something like:

```
headers = { 'Authorization' : 'Bearer {0}'.format(token),
            'Accept' : 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json' }
```

Then you need to actually build some payload to send. What I've done before with this library is just pass it a JSON string. So you'd have something like this:

```
new_user = graph_client.post('{0}/users'.format(graph_url)), headers = headers, json = user_json_string)
```

Recommendation for future posts: don't post images of your code. Just post the code. It makes it much easier for folks to help :)

Comment: Thank you Jason.
I tried as per your guidance but it still didn't get solved.
I am posting my code below please refer my view.py and graph_helper.py files. I guess I am doing wrong while calling the methods or sending data. Kindly look into it and please guide me

Comment: Ok you're passing a dictionary, not a JSON string, so try changing from "json=context1" to "data=context1". Alternatively you may try "json=context1.to_json()" (or something like that, going from memory here)

Comment: I have used "json=context1" , "data=context1", "data=json.dumps(context1)". Nothing worked. According to your suggestion I tried "json=context1.to_json()" but I am getting error that {'dict' object has no attribute 'to_json'}.

Comment: This old sample might help you: https://github.com/jasonjoh/pythoncontacts/blob/7929f614eb281af00d9b68a409240c7c1334ac7d/contacts/o365service.py#L205. They may have changed the Requests API since then but that’s how I got it to work back then. When I get more time to look at this I can provide a more concrete answer.

Comment: Well, thanks for the referral to your project. that's great project. it might come in hand to me. But since it was written in the older version. so now it is giving error and I tried to resolve the error but I am not able to resolve the last 6 errors. Anyways, Do you have any Csharp code reference for same activity 'GET' & 'POST' method. I am thinking to give it try through Csharp.

Answer (score 0):

To call Microsoft Graph API, you must provide a access token in the request headers. Here is an example of the request.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Content-type: application/json

{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "displayName-value",
  "mailNickname": "mailNickname-value",
  "userPrincipalName": "upn-value@tenant-value.onmicrosoft.com",
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
    "password": "password-value"
  }
}
```

[image]

There are two ways to get auth tokens.

[Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user)

[Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am sorry I didn't mention earlier that I have access auth token and I am able to fetch the data from azure ad using 'GET' request and now I want to add some changes so for that I need an example of Django POST code

Comment: Hi did you got anything on it

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```
from tutorial.graph_helper import *
from django.urls import reverse
from tutorial.auth_helper import get_sign_in_url, get_token_from_code, store_token, store_user, remove_user_and_token, get_token
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
import dateutil.parser

def home(request):
  context = initialize_context(request)

  return render(request, 'tutorial/home.html', context)

def userslist(request):
  context = initialize_context(request)
  token = get_token(request)
  usersdata = get_users(token)
  if usersdata :
    #for user in usersdata['value']
    print ('users fetched')
    print (usersdata)
  else:
    print('no output')

  print('yeta ka')
  context['usersdata'] = usersdata['value']
  return render(request, 'tutorial/userslist.html',context)

def groupslist(request):
  context = initialize_context(request)
  token = get_token(request)
  groupsdata = get_groups(token)
  if groupsdata :
    #for group in groupsdata['value']
    print ('groups fetched')
    print (groupsdata)
  else:
    print('no output')

  print('yeta ka')
  context['groupsdata'] = groupsdata['value']
  return render(request, 'tutorial/groupslist.html',context)

def newuserindex(request):
  return render(request, 'createsingleuser.html')

def createsingleuser(request):
  context = initialize_context(request)
  token = get_token(request)
  if request.method =='POST':
    context = request.POST  
    context1 = {
      "accountEnabled": 'true',
      "city": context['city'],
      "country": context['country'],
      "department": context['department'],
      "displayName": context['displayName'],
      "givenName": context['givenName'],
      "jobTitle": context['jobTitle'],
      "mailNickname": context['mailNickname'],
      "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration",
      "passwordProfile": {
        "password": "Test1234",
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": 'false'
      },
      "officeLocation": context['officeLocation'],
      "postalCode": context['postalCode'],
      "preferredLanguage": context['preferredLanguage'],
      "state": context['state'],
      "streetAddress": context['streetAddress'],
      "surname": context['surname'],
      "mobilePhone": context['mobilePhone'],
      "usageLocation": context['mobilePhone'],
      "userPrincipalName": context['userPrincipalName']
    }
    newuser = create_user(token,context1)
    print (newuser)

  return render(request, 'tutorial/createsingleuser.html', context)

def initialize_context(request):
  context = {}

  # Check for any errors in the session
  error = request.session.pop('flash_error', None)

  if error != None:
    context['errors'] = []
    context['errors'].append(error)

  # Check for user in the session
  context['user'] = request.session.get('user', {'is_authenticated': False})
  return context

def sign_in(request):
  # Get the sign-in URL
  sign_in_url, state = get_sign_in_url()
  # Save the expected state so we can validate in the callback
  request.session['auth_state'] = state
  # Redirect to the Azure sign-in page
  return HttpResponseRedirect(sign_in_url)

def callback(request):
  # Get the state saved in session
  expected_state = request.session.pop('auth_state', '')
  # Make the token request
  token = get_token_from_code(request.get_full_path(), expected_state)

  # Get the user's profile
  user = get_user(token)

  # Save token and user
  store_token(request, token)
  store_user(request, user)

  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))

def sign_out(request):
  # Clear out the user and token
  remove_user_and_token(request)

  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))

def calendar(request):
  context = initialize_context(request)

  token = get_token(request)

  events = get_calendar_events(token)

  if events:
    # Convert the ISO 8601 date times to a datetime object
    # This allows the Django template to format the value nicely
    for event in events['value']:
      event['start']['dateTime'] = dateutil.parser.parse(event['start']['dateTime'])
      event['end']['dateTime'] = dateutil.parser.parse(event['end']['dateTime'])

    context['events'] = events['value']

  return render(request, 'tutorial/calendar.html', context)
```

graph_helper.py

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
import json
import requests


graph_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0'


def get_user(token):
  graph_client = OAuth2Session(token=token)
  # Send GET to /me
  user = graph_client.get('{0}/me'.format(graph_url))
  # Return the JSON result
  return user.json()

def get_calendar_events(token):
  graph_client = OAuth2Session(token=token)

  # Configure query parameters to
  # modify the results
  query_params = {
    '$select': 'subject,organizer,start,end',
    '$orderby': 'createdDateTime DESC'
  }

  # Send GET to /me/events
  events = graph_client.get('{0}/me/events'.format(graph_url), params=query_params)
  # Return the JSON result
  return events.json()

def get_users(token):
  graph_client = OAuth2Session(token=token)
  # Send GET to /users
  users = graph_client.get('{0}/users'.format(graph_url))
  # Return the JSON result
  return users.json()

def get_groups(token):
  graph_client = OAuth2Session(token=token)
  # Send GET to /groups
  groups = graph_client.get('{0}/groups'.format(graph_url))
  # Return the JSON result
  return groups.json()

def create_user(token, context1):
  graph_client = OAuth2Session(token=token)
  headers = { 'Authorization' : 'Bearer {0}'.format(token),
            'Accept' : 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json' }
  # newuser = graph_client.post('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users', headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json", data=context1, })
  newuser = graph_client.post('{0}/users'.format(graph_url), headers = headers, json = context1)
  return newuser
```